# Swift - How to get WidgetLocation from WidgetCenter

Tags: swift, widgetkit, ios17

I know I can get [`WidgetInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/widgetinfo) from [`WidgetCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/widgetcenter) using [`getCurrentConfigurations(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/widgetcenter/getcurrentconfigurations(_:)). But, how can I access new [`WidgetLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/widgetlocation) from that info?

I can't find anything in the documentation. If there is `widgetFamily` field, there should be `location` as well, right?

Answer (score 1):

As of now Apple doesn’t tell us where the widget is located as of right now you can use this type to “disfavor” locations

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/widgetconfiguration/disfavoredlocations%28_:for:%29?changes=latest_major&language=objc

So in theory if you don’t want a particular “small” widget to show up in the “Lock Screen” you would disfavor it.

```
 lockScreenOnlyConfig
.disfavoredLocations([.lockScreen], for: [.systemSmall])
```

Comment: Hi, I know I can disfavor some locations. My question is not about showing widgets but about getting info of added widgets.

Comment: So you suggest creating two different widget kinds and distinguish location based on kind? Something like widgetA_homeScreen, widgetA_standBy?

Comment: @RobertDresler Yes, basically instead of reacting to the location be proactive and limit where a widget can be presented.

Comment: I actually don't want to do anything with the widget itself. I just need to get info about configuration and its location in the main app through WidgetCenter because I need to work with the fact that the widget on standby location was added.

Comment: @RobertDresler it isn’t possible reactively right now. You can submit a feature request and see if Apple adds this feature in a future update. Again proactively you could by separating configuations.